# Get only tags except text through regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Can you please tell how to get only tags through Regex in c#?

For example,

```
Input:
    <name>Wen-Hsiang <surname value
      ="AUTH_16896">Kung</surname>
    </name> 

My output will look like:
<name><surname value
      ="AUTH_16896"></surname>
    </name>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case better you use XML parsing,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<name><surname value="AUTH_16896"></surname></name>");

foreach(XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes){
   string text = node.InnerText; //or loop through its children as well
}
```

try this.

Comment: I agree but I would consider using the Linq to XML API as it might be a bit less verbose.  There are lots of ways to fail to parse valid XML if you are using regular expressions, so unless your XML is very simple, I would use a parsing API.

Comment: Yes i agree but its depending upon requirement.

Comment: Sir but this solution is not suitable our requirement...can you please give me another solution or provide any regex pattern

Comment: Regex is working fine, if node have not changeable if node has change in same repeat cycle value regex has been always fail.

Comment: my approach is that select all tags in xml file and remove it and get only text values and stored in a list

Comment: hello please reply me